# Replace values based on two columns in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a really large df.

```
UserID      Name   TempName
Matt      458488   None
Matt      458488   None
Matt      458488   None
Matt      458488   None
Matt      458488   None
Pablo     213123   8748
Pablo     213123   8748
Pablo     213123   8748
Pablo     213123   8748
Pablo     213123   8748
Pablo     213123   8748
Pablo     213123   8748
Kate       2442    None
 ...      ...      ...
```

Need to replace `None` in `tempName` by `Name` Values. But only there where users has `None` in `Temp` Val. If `User` as Pablo in `Temp != None`, should pass and tempValue should be unchanged.

None is a string, no NaN

Example result of TempName:

```
   UserID      Name   TempName
    Matt      458488   458488   
    Matt      458488   458488   
    Matt      458488   458488   
    Matt      458488   458488   
    Matt      458488   458488   
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Pablo     213123   8748
    Kate       2442    2442    
     ...      ...      ...
```

Now my code works on simple but really slow loop and if.

```
For record in df:
if df.TempName.iloc[record] == 'None':
   df.TempName.iloc[record] = df.Name.iloc[record]
else:
   pass
```

I looking for faster an maybe better solution of this problem. Maybe someone have a better idea? On SO i found only a solution of merging or concat whole cols, I need to do that partialy. DF has 9mln records.

It's not duplicated coz None is not NaN value, just string. I can't replace str'None' to NaN too.

Comment: Use `df.TempName = df.TempName.fillna(df.Name)`

Comment: Nothing change. None is a string not a NaN val, maybe it'a a problem?

Comment: Yes, it should be problem, how working `df.loc[df.Name == 'None'] = df.TempName` ?

Comment: I got `ValueError: shape mismatch:`. But thanks for the advice, I will try to figure it in this way.